# Symfony: use parameter from route in other function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

My controller:

```
**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}


/**
* @Route("/title/{title}", name="Title")
* @param Request $request
* @param $title
* @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
*/
public function TitleAction(Request $request, $title)
{



    //Some DB calls to retrieve data with 'where .. = $title'
    return $this->render('default/title.html.twig', array(
            'title' => $title,
            'results' => $results[0],
            'cs' => $cs,
            'gs' => $gs,

            ...
            }
}



/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function updateDataAction(Request $request)
{


        //Here I also want to use $title so I can use it in my query

        $dataCS = $request->get('inputCS');
        $dataGS = $request->get('inputGS');

        if(!empty($dataGS) and !empty($dataCS)) {
            // $results = Query
        } 
        else {
            // $results = Query

        }

        return new JsonResponse(array('results' => $results[0]));
}
```

My AJAX call in script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#filter1").change(function() {
        var inputCS = $(this).val();
        if(inputCs.length >= 1) {
            var data = {inputCS: inputCS};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ROOT_URL + "default/update/data",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 3000,
                success: function(results){
                    //some innerHTML replacements
                  if(result.low === null) {
                     document.getElementById("low").innerHTML = 'N/A'
                  }
                  else {
                     document.getElementById("low").innerHTML = 
                     Math.floor(Number(result.result.low));
                  }
                },
                error: function() {
                   //
                }
            })
        }


    });
})
```

My twig:
Filters:

```
<select id="filter1">
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    {% for c in cs %}
        <option value="{{ c.name }}">{{ c.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="filter2">
    <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
    {% for g in gs %}
        <option value="{{ g.name }}">{{ g.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Where result is used:

```
{% if results.low != 0 %}
    <p class="amount" id="low">{{ results.low|round(0, 'floor') }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p class="amount">N/A</p>
{% endif %}
```

A bit background info: With function TitleAction I show some results on the twig page that is based on the value from the route (title/{title}) - with the help of some DB calls (with a `where` clause). On this page I have 2 filters which you can use to filter the results that are shown on the page. When a filter is triggered (value selected) I do an AJAX call to the updateDataAction function where I do again some specific DB calls, but with an extra `where` clause and the filter as value. I return the filtered result set with a JSON respons to my AJAX call. At the success I do some interHTML replacements on the original values.

My question is the following. How can I pass or use the same value {title} from the route (title/{title}) so I can also here use that specific value in my query.

I tried to also use the `@route` annotation on that function, but no results and the `$request->query...` didn't help either.

Comment: In your JS you have `success: function(results){` but then refer to `result.low` and `result.result.low` - I assume this is just due to some code you've left out from the question, not actual errors in your code with the wrong variable names?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, what I'd do is have the `{{results.title}}` in an HTML attribute that you can read with your JS when making the AJAX request.

e.g.

```
<body data-title="{{results.title}}">
```

Then in your JS:

```
$("#filter1").change(function() {
    var inputCS = $(this).val();
    var title = $('body').data('title');

    if(inputCs.length >= 1) {
        var data = {
            inputCS: inputCS,
            title: title
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ROOT_URL + "default/update/data",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function(results){
                // ...
            },
            error: function() {
               //
            }
        });
    }
});
```